# Azure function failing on 500 - ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\home\site''

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Azure function started failing with:

```
Result: Failure
Exception: Worker was unable to load function StartStopVms: 'Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\home\site''
Stack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\home\site'
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1461:7)
    at toRealPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:241:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:310:24)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:633:25)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at FunctionLoader.load (D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12858\32bit\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:18562:22)
```

What could be the cause? It's a nodejs function deployed on windows. It's set to "run from zip" (code is located in blob storage).
It worked until yesterday. There was no change to function's code.

Thanks.

Comment: Go to Kudu to see whether there is a site folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your function app and click "Platform features" --> "Advanced tools (Kudu)" --> "Debug console" --> "CMD" to check if the "site" is exist.
[image]